Why is customtkinter label height not working?
I am trying to limit the height of a Customtkinter label but no matter what I set the height value to it doesn't seem to do anything. I am using the Spotify API to fetch the name of the track which is currently playing, however, if the song name is long, it breaks the interface. I am also using wraplength to wrap the text.
self.nowplayingsong = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text="Song name", fg_color="transparent", font=("Arial", 100), anchor="w", justify='left', wraplength=700)
    self.nowplayingsong.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100, pady=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W")
    self.get_current_track()

Short song name:

Long song name:

I have tried setting the label height to different values as mentioned in the Customtkinter documentation but it doesn't seem to do anything.

It is because the font size is large.

Changing the height of the Label widget directly won't be effective if the height is lesser than the actual text-height. The only ways to achieve this is:

Changing the font size

Changing pady value

Changing both font size and pady
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()

nowplayingsong = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Song name", font=("Helvetica", 16))
nowplayingsong.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=100, pady=0, columnspan=3, sticky="W")

# Achieve indirect height using font size and pady
label_with_height = ctk.CTkLabel(root, text="Now the height has changed", font=("Helvetica", 36) )
label_with_height.grid(row=3, column=0, pady =20)

root.mainloop()




line 10, in 
label_with_height.pack(pady=20) _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

Should be label_with_height.grid(row=3, column=0)

The height of a CTkLabel can be set but it won't be effective if the value of height is less than the actual height of the text of the label for a specified font size.  If it is larger, it will work.  So "You can't change the height of the Label widget directly" is invalid if it is a CTkLabel.

@toyotaSupra, Thank you. edited. (I got used to pack())

@acw1668, Edited. But it's other way round. If the height is set larger than the actual text height, then it won't be effective.

No, what you say is incorrect.  It works when the height option is larger than the height of the text for a specified font size.  For example, if font size is 100 and the height is 500, then the label will have height of 500.

@acw1668, Let me check once again

Yes @acw1668, You are right. tested and edited. I had wrong understanding.
